# What is the Python equivalent of Excel's Beta distribution?

Tags: python, excel, scipy, beta-distribution

What is the Python equivalent of the Beta distribution in Excel?
In Excel, the formula is:

```
=BETA.DIST(A2,A3,A4,FALSE,A5,A6).
```

This gives the Beta probability density function for the given parameters,
and we get the result as some decimal value.

But the [Python SciPy reference does not give](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html) the function parameters and its definition in a similar form as Excel.

I am not getting how to do this in SciPy and pass the parameter correctly.

Answer (score 4):

as you can see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html), the probability density function of the beta distribution in scipy has exactly the same three parameters as excel ([excel docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/BETA-DIST-function-11188c9c-780a-42c7-ba43-9ecb5a878d31)).

`ALPHA` is equivalent to `a` and represents a parameter of the distribution.

`BETA` is equivalent to `b` and represents a parameter of the distribution.

`X` is equivalent to `x` and value at which the distribution should be evaluated.

Weather or not the `Cumulativ` parameter in excel is True is represented by calling different functions in scipy. If you want the cumulative distribution (`Cumulativ = True`) you just call `myBeta.cdf(<myParams>)`, if you want the probability density function (`Cumulativ = False`) you call `myBeta.pdf(<myParams>)`.
That means:

```
BETA.DIST(X,Alpha,Beta,TRUE) <=>
scipy.stats.beta.cdf(x,a,b)
```

and

```
BETA.DIST(X,Alpha,Beta,FALSE) <=>
scipy.stats.beta.pdf(x,a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Excel `BETA.DIST` function with signature

```
BETA.DIST(x,alpha,beta,cumulative,[A],[B])
```

with `cumulative = FALSE`, use the function `scipy.stats.beta.pdf` as follows:

```
from scipy import stats
p = stats.beta.pdf(x, alpha, beta, loc=A, scale=B-A)
```

In other words, set `loc` to be the lower bound of the support interval [A, B], and set `scale` to the length of the interval.

For example, the [documentation for `BETA.DIST`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/BETA-DIST-function-11188c9c-780a-42c7-ba43-9ecb5a878d31) includes the example

```
=BETA.DIST(A2,A3,A4,FALSE,A5,A6)
```

where `A2=2`, `A3=8`, `A4=10`, `A5=1` and `A6=3`.  The value of the function is reported to be `1.4837646`.  The corresponding expression using scipy is:

```
In [59]: from scipy import stats

In [60]: x = 2

In [61]: alpha = 8

In [62]: beta = 10

In [63]: a = 1

In [64]: b = 3

In [65]: stats.beta.pdf(x, alpha, beta, loc=a, scale=b-a)
Out[65]: 1.4837646484375009
```

---

For the case `cumulative=TRUE`, use the function `scipy.stats.beta.cdf`.  The same example given above reports the value of the PDF to be `0.6854706`.  Here's the calculation using scipy:

```
In [66]: stats.beta.cdf(x, alpha, beta, loc=a, scale=b-a)
Out[66]: 0.6854705810546875
```